# How to show the id div when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have sevral div,when I hover on one of them I want to show the id on the div

```
<div id="display_id_div" >hover me</div>
```

Thanks.
my html

```
<div id="display_id_div" >hover me</div>
<div id="div1" >hover me</div>
<div id="div2" >hover me</div>
<div id="div3" >hover me</div>
```

.
jquery code:

```
$(div).hover(function(){
    $("#display_id_div") =  $(this.id);
})​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').hover(function(){ // attach hover callback to all divs.
    $('#display_id_div').html(this.id); // change display_id_div innerHTML value
                                        // to the hovered id.
})​;
```

Comment: +1 here you go, People with laptops but no thoughts :) + need some chill pills around

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing function and assignment, you can't assign something to a function call.

You got several errors in your code:

`$(div).hover(function(){`

What is `div`? a variable or? If you mean to select `div`s in your html you need to do:

`$('div[id^=div]')`

The `[id^=div]` part is to select `div`s with id starting with `div`

so now your code looks like

```
$('div[id^=div]').hover(function() {
   $("#display_id_div") =  $(this.id);
});
```

You need to modify the `innerHTML` of `#display_id_div`, so you use

```
$('#display_id_div').html(this.id);
```

If you notice, there are two ways of using `.html()`, as a setter and getter. It acts here as a setter, given an argument. If called without an argument, it's a getter

Final code:

```
$('div[id^=div]').hover(function() {
    $('#display_id_div').html(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Someone here is on a downvoting spree! Take my +1.(anyway it's a better answer than mine.)

Comment: @gdoron And 16 seconds ago, someone downvoted my other answer... :S, some dude is downvote-stalking me :(

Answer (score 2):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jJRJT/4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/jJRJT/5/

**code**

```
$("div").hover(function(){
      alert(this.id);
})​;
```

**or**

to put it in html

`$("#display_id_div").html(this.id);`

Comment: Wasn't me bu I'd guess it's your use if the alert. The OP asked to display the id in the div.

Comment: One can only assume it's because your answer alerts the ID, yet the question being asked is how to put the ID into another div.

Comment: make use of html function because he want to display the thing in the div not alert ....

Comment: @All lol http://jsfiddle.net/jJRJT/5/ hope no one angry now; can we remove the -1 please

Comment: @PranayRana thanks updated man! everyone seems short today :))

Comment: @PranayRana lol ha ha someone is on spree :) o well I will +1 you man no sweat!

Comment: @Tats_innit - this so where people downvote your answer for silly msitakes just to keep there answer up...ha ha ha ...

Comment: @PranayRana. Actually NiftyDude got a downvote when he had three upvotes and was the only one with positive vote casts... I I upvoted him, so it can be something else here.

Comment: @gdoron lol whoever it is should be really feeling low :) anyhow craziness to its extreme and wrong people with keyboard and mice :P

Answer (score 0):

just write this line of code you need to make use of `.html()` function jquery

```
$("#display_id_div").html( $(this).attr('id'));
```

you final code will be

```
 $("div").hover(function()
  { 
    $("#display_id_div").html(  $(this).attr('id'));
  });​
```

Comment: You might want to encapsulate that `div` in quotes, eg `$('div')`

Comment: And after re-reading it, you store the a jQuery object in innerHTML...?

Comment: @gdoron - its already done and here more concern is to make use of html function not on the selector........anyways no issue

Comment: I'm talking about this: `$("#display_id_div").html(  $(this.id));` line, you assign a jQuery object as the innerHTML.

Comment: @PranayRana `this.id` bru not $(this) I reckon

Comment: I'm not sure why did you find it helpful downvote my question... but Good luck it with that attitude.!

Comment: No, `$(this).id` will give you undefined. but you can keep it, and downvote other **valid** answers.

Comment: @gdoron - i m not downvoted my answer can i send you the image of my score that can give you idea give me you mail id ...

Comment: @gdoron - its updated now and working fine ...in hurry i made some mistake but its upto the mark now...

Comment: Now just please change from `$(this).attr('id')` to => `this.id`